# Trying to grep the output of fs_usage with poor results

Tags: mac, terminal, grep, hosts

I'm trying to figure out what process is periodically and silently erasing the contents of the /etc/hosts file on a Mac. I tried using:

```
sudo fs_usage | grep hosts
```

but it only generates a few seconds of output and then returns me to the command prompt, after which trying to restart fs_usage tells me:

```
ktrace_start: Resource busy
```

Once that happens, the only way I know how to re-enable fs_usage is to restart the computer, as I can't find either fs_usage or the ktrace process. Piping the output of grep to a text file generated nothing and behaved the same way.

1. Why is grep ceasing all output  after a few seconds?
2. How can I make fs_usage available again without restarting?

Answer (score 6):

I have also encountered same problem today and after some trail and error, I got it working without restarting the mac.

Try to find the pid of all the processes with name `fs_usage` and kill it.

```
$ ps -e | grep fs_usage
```

Then kill the processes using the pid

```
$sudo kill -9 pid
```

But your statement

> I can't find either fs_usage or the ktrace process.

I didn't understand why you didn't find the process.

Try my solution and update me!

Comment: The problem happens when fs_usage is running and then terminates without being sent a quit signal (Control C or such) and either that quit leaves the ktrace locked or the ktrace lock is causing fs_usage to abort early. I haven't gotten this to reproduce and pick apart, but this still happened on occasion on 10.13.6

Comment: @bmike Thanks for the “why” part